# Getting prblem while installing pyATS

Tags: automated-tests, installation

$pip install pyats

Downloading/unpacking pyats
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyats

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for pyats Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpToVcvF

Comment: try to upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use both 4.x.x and 5.x.x pyats with Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6. Python 3.7 is not supported yet.
Source: https://github.com/CiscoTestAutomation/pyats/issues/7

Comment: This is **not** a link only answer. The link explains that you have to use Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6, this is the essential answer provided by the link. The link provides only additional info (as, for example, 'pyats doesn't yet support Python 3.7')